# Last column of tabular isn't vertically centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm in trouble with the last column of my array. It's not vertically centered. I'd like to use as less package as possible, here my code and the result.

```
\usepackage{array}

%Some Text

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%Some Text

\begin{tabular}{L{0.2\textwidth} C{0.2\textwidth} C{0.2\textwidth} C{0.2\textwidth}}
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}
\textbf{Pays}                       & \textbf{Volumes 2016} & \textbf{Part de marché (VP + VU)} & \textbf{Variation 2016 vs 2015 (en points)}\\[2em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
France                              & 361 670               & 27,4 \%                           & + 0,5                                \\[1em]
Italie                              & 110 681               & 9,7 \%                            & + 0,5                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Allemagne                           & 97 671                & 5,2 \%                            & + 0,3                                \\[1em]
Espagne                             & 87 136                & 12,3 \%                           & - 0,7                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Turquie                             & 79 269                & 18,1 \%                           & + 2,4                                \\[1em]
Royaume-Uni                         & 71 967                & 4,4 \%                            & + 0,4                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Brésil                              & 69 874                & 7,3 \%                            & + 0,3                                \\[1em]
Inde                                & 61 895                & 3,8 \%                            & + 2,3                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Russie                              & 52 041                & 7,7 \%                            & + 0,4                                \\[1em]
Belgique + Luxembourg               & 51 466                & 13,5 \%                           & - 0,1                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Corée du sud                        & 46 917                & 7,1 \%                            & + 0,7                                \\[1em]
Aregntine                           & 39 491                & 12,2 \%                           & + 1,6                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Iran                                & 34 124                & 5,8 \%                            & + 4,6                                \\[1em]
Maroc                               & 31 034                & 37,0 \%                           & - 1,3                                \\[1em]
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
Algérie                             & 29 132                & 41,7 \%                           & + 10,0                               \\[1em]
\end{tabular}
```

EDIT: Here is the result :

[image: Result of the previous code]

Comment: Can you complete your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) please, so it compile once one copy past your code ie: add a complete code `\documentclass{...} ... \begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: I also suggest to use `siunitx` for the number alignment and `%` display

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the `[2em]`. I propose to change the value of `arraystretch` instead, and to improve the table & simplify its code with `siunitx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, makecell, siunitx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\definecolor{webgrey}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-column-width=2.8cm, output-decimal-marker={,}}
\rowcolors{2}{}{webgrey}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}S[table-format=6.0]S[table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post = {\,\%}]<{\,\%}S[table-format=+1.1]}% C{0.2\textwidth}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}
  \textbf{Pays}         & {\thead{Volumes 2016}} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\thead{Part de marché &        \\ (VP + VU)}}  & {\thead{Variation\\ 2016 vs 2015\\ (en points)}}\\
  France                & 361 670                & 27,4                                         & + 0,5  \\
  Italie                & 110 681                & 9,7                                          & + 0,5  \\
  Allemagne             & 97 671                 & 5,2                                          & + 0,3  \\
  Espagne               & 87 136                 & 12,3                                         & - 0,7  \\
  Turquie               & 79 269                 & 18,1                                         & + 2,4  \\
  Royaume-Uni           & 71 967                 & 4,4                                          & + 0,4  \\
  Brésil               & 69 874                 & 7,3                                          & + 0,3  \\
  Inde                  & 61 895                 & 3,8                                          & + 2,3  \\
  Russie                & 52 041                 & 7,7                                          & + 0,4  \\
  Belgique + Luxembourg & 51 466                 & 13,5                                         & - 0,1  \\
  Corée du sud         & 46 917                 & 7,1                                          & + 0,7  \\
  Argentine             & 39 491                 & 12,2                                         & + 1,6  \\
  Iran                  & 34 124                 & 5,8                                          & + 4,6  \\
  Maroc                 & 31 034                 & 37,0                                         & - 1,3  \\
  Algérie              & 29 132                 & 41,7                                         & + 10,0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you do not have access to all the packages, here is a simplified version, without the numbers alignment:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{webgrey}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{}{webgrey}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{l@{} C{2.8cm} C{2.8cm}<{\,\%} >{$}C{2.8cm}<{$}}%
  \rowcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}
  \textbf{Pays}         & \bfseries Volumes 2016 & \bfseries Part de marché \newline (VP + VU)  & \multicolumn{1}{C{2.8cm}}{\bfseries Variation\newline 2016 vs 2015\newline (en points)}\\
  France                & 361 670                & 27,4                                         & + 0,5  \\
  Italie                & 110 681                & 9,7                                          & + 0,5  \\
  Allemagne             & 97 671                 & 5,2                                          & + 0,3  \\
  Espagne               & 87 136                 & 12,3                                         & - 0,7  \\
  Turquie               & 79 269                 & 18,1                                         & + 2,4  \\
  Royaume-Uni           & 71 967                 & 4,4                                          & + 0,4  \\
  Brésil               & 69 874                 & 7,3                                          & + 0,3  \\
  Inde                  & 61 895                 & 3,8                                          & + 2,3  \\
  Russie                & 52 041                 & 7,7                                          & + 0,4  \\
  Belgique + Luxembourg & 51 466                 & 13,5                                         & - 0,1  \\
  Corée du sud         & 46 917                 & 7,1                                          & + 0,7  \\
  Argentine             & 39 491                 & 12,2                                         & + 1,6  \\
  Iran                  & 34 124                 & 5,8                                          & + 4,6  \\
  Maroc                 & 31 034                 & 37,0                                         & - 1,3  \\
  Algérie              & 29 132                 & 41,7                                         & + 10,0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which package are really necessary between those ? I have to manually install all of them because I have a VPN blocking not allowed connections.

Edit: Because I don't understand your code

Comment: Normally all, but we can find work-arounds for `makecell`, for instance (it is used to have the `\thead` command at our disposal). Whicht are the packages which aren't installed?

Comment: `makecell, siunitx` and `lmodern`

Comment: What??? Even lmodern, which is the recommended font for languages with accented letters?  What's that VPN?

Comment: I'm working on MikTeX portable in a Huge company (Renault) so they block connection from the outside for security reason

Comment: You should ask your administrator. Otherwise you'll always have this kind of problem. You may put forward they're only text files.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm finishing my internship tomorrow so it won't be usefull now.

Comment: @Biboozz: I've posted a version without these packages (and without the alignment of numbers. Please let me know if it compiles for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late. No it doesn't work, I have a lot of errors, maybe because my tabular is within a figure environement.

Comment: I think the problem come from `<{\\%} >{$}C{2.8cm}<{$}}%` (maybe because of escaping)

first error : `! Paragraph ended before \@@array was complete.`

Comment: Oh! yes. It's a typo: it should be `<{\,\%}`, not `<{\\%}`. The rest is unchanged. Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the answer.